# How to make full button clickable on SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have two buttons, a create and a delete button that only work when I click on the actual text written on the button. I'd like to make the full button clickable. I tried the answers left on similar posts like this but none seemed to work so I'm trying my luck to see if any of you have a solution for me. Below is my code, thanks in advance for all the help!

```
struct RoundedEdgesButton : View {
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled

    var text: LocalizedStringKey
    var action: () -> Void
    var bgColor: Color

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text(text)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10,
                                        leading: 10,
                                        bottom: 10,
                                        trailing: 10))
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .cornerRadius(6.0)
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                        .fill(bgColor)
        )
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code for `RoundedEdgesButton`?

Comment: I second the above. Ideally, you'd remove all the code that isn't necessary for this question (and doesn't compile because of missing code) and include all of the relevant code -- see: [mre].

Comment: @aheze thanks for the tip, i took away the unnecessary code and added the RoundedEdgesButton's code

Comment: @jnpdx updated, sorry about that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put all the modifiers *inside* the button's label.

```
struct RoundedEdgesButton: View {
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled

    var text: LocalizedStringKey
    var action: () -> Void
    var bgColor: Color

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                
                Text(text)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(
                        EdgeInsets(
                            top: 10,
                            leading: 10,
                            bottom: 10,
                            trailing: 10
                        )
                    )
                
                Spacer()
            }

            /// inside the `Button`
            .cornerRadius(6.0)
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                    .fill(bgColor)
            )
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
    }
}
```